# Compare strings that can come in a different internal order

Tags: java, string, junit, compare, assert

I'm writing a JUnit test that check messages (one message per line) inside one unified String. The format is as follows:

> [* Message for Alice *]
>
> Hey, first message
>
> Second message
>
> [* Message for Jim *]
>
> Holler
>
> Are you there?
>
> [* General Messages *]
>
> Welcome everyone!
>
> This is yet another message.

The problem is that the actual string's order that I receive may change (except for the General Messages that always comes at the end of the string). For example: one time I can get Jim's messages first, so when I try to use assertEquals() the test fails. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code that generate the messages, so I can't make any modifications.

What is the best way to compare these strings and validate that they're the same?

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, you should re-write your test so it can handle different orders. If you're asking how to do that, post some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should re-organize your tests to address arbitrary re-ordering, for example, like this:

- Split the string into individual messages
- Separate general messages and all other messages
- Order expected and actual messages in the same order (e.g. alphabetical)
- Compare ordered lists of expected and actual messages. Now that they are ordered the same, they should equal item-by-item
- Check that the general messages come after all other messages in the actual message stream.

Comment: +1 having to sort the output to ensure the order is desperate but it is better than not testing.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better compare `Set`s of messages, as the fuzzy string comparison you're after is going to be too tricky...

Comment: +1.  This is nice and easy, because if your set classes extend `AbstractSet` (which things like `TreeSet` and `HashSet` both do), then the `equals()` method checks whether the two sets contain all the same strings, which is what you want.